# MySQL SELECT only if value higher than next highest by XXX

Tags: mysql, unix, select, timestamp

I'd like to select a field in MySQL table (unix timestamp) only if greater than next highest by 7200. How to do that?

I mean something like this:

SELECT id FROM registers WHERE time IS BIGGER THAN NEXT time BY 7200?

TABLE registers: id (int_8), time(int_11), description(text)

EXAMPLE:

```
1, 127586113, This is description
2, 127587399, This is description (NEXT HIGHEST)
3, 127588524, This is description (HIGHEST, LET'S SAY EQUAL TO NOW())
```

Comment: Please add your table structure, example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id 
from registers r
where not exists 
      (select 1 from registers where time < r.time and time > r.time - 7200)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from registers
WHERE time = ( select min(time)
                        from registers
                        where time > 7200);
```

If I understood the problem correctly, this should do it.